# Math module VS PostGIS

Tags: postgis, mathematics

I have to compute intersection points between GIS polygons and imaginary lines I draw using a script of mine and I wonder if it would be relevant to use PostGIS instead of a Math module to catch intersection points?

By math module (or library) I think about a mathematic module as I work on a Python script. So that is a "python math module".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind that ST_INTERSECTIONS will make use of a spatial index whereas your math library may not.  Not only must you determine if a line intersects a polygon, but which polygons to test for each line.  A good spatial index with possibly fish-netting of these polygons can vastly speed up a spatial query like this.  Not to mention if you have a large amount of polygons, you'll save time by not having to load all of the polygons into memory.

Unless you are loading a lot of data from this query from PostGIS over a slow network on another machine, the overhead is probably negligible.

Answer (score 6):

If by "using a math module," you mean manually writing out formulas to compute an intersection, then you should really use PostGIS. No sense in reinventing the wheel!

Do note, however, that your data will need to be loaded into a PostGIS database.

So if your original data came in the form of shapefiles, you'll need to load that into a PostGIS database with [shp2pgsql](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ch04.html#shp2pgsql_usage), for example. And if your script is generating a start- and endpoint for a line as human-readable (x,y) coordinates, you would need to convert those coordinates into a geometry using [ST_GeomFromText](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html).

Answer (score 3):

I think that the Shapely Python package would work great for what you need. It uses the exact same geometry library that PostGIS uses, without the need for an underlying RDBMS.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely